# Android: AsyncTask cancel() issues

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an EditText and an AsyncTask class. Whenever the text changes in the EditText, the AsyncTask class's object created and called execute() on it with the string. And the doBackground() is called which has only a single function which  in turn has multiple for loops one after another. A new object for AsyncTask is created whenever, the text changes. 
When the text changes, the old Async object has to be cancelled and the new one should take control. But when I call cancel on the object, the old one continues to run and seems to call onPostExecute().
Is there a way to avoid this. I mean, can I kill/(stop running) the old asyncTask object completely before running the new one?

**EDIT**
This is my code,

```
if (getSuggestions1.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
    getSuggestions1.cancel(true);
    getSuggestions1 = new GetSuggestions1();
    getSuggestions1.execute(new String[] { str });
}
```

As you can see I am calling execute() immediately after calling cancel on the same object. Also, as I said, I have multiple for loops(6). I am worried the function, the isCancelled(), returns true for one of the for loops as the object initialized immediately.

Comment: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10882600/1289716) answer that may help you...

Comment: "As you can see I am calling execute() immediately after calling cancel on the same object." They are NOT the same objects. You're calling it in the same pointer that after the 'new' keyword it is pointing to a new object.

Comment: See **Cancelling a Task** on [this Android API doc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already given answers.

Stopping (cancelling) an `AsyncTask` is a cooperative action. This means that simply calling `AsyncTask.cancel()` is not enough. This call just sets a cancelled status (a flag) and does nothing more. Your `AsyncTask` implementation should provide a cooperation (help) in order to actually stop processing. Specifically this means that if you want your `AsyncTask`'s cancellability to be highly responsive you need to arrange checking for cancelled status rather frequently. So put `if (isCancelled()) { return null; }` statements inside of your loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like

```
while (!isCancelled()) {
    // processing
}
```

or

```
if (!isCancelled()) {
    // processing
}
```

The if-sentence is good if you're having many loops, at least that's what I've experienced. These should be used in `doInBackground()` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a boolean flag called shouldCancel in your class extending ASyncTask and periodically check it in the `doInBackground()`, if it's set, then return from `doInBackground` method.

Comment: AsyncTask already has [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()) exactly for this purpose.  No need to create another flag.