# how to terminate AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I'm currently have an Android application with 3 activities.

Main activity:

Constantly polling a Xml file using AsyncTask and update UI using onPostExecute.

The AsyncTask is loop by:

```
Handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, Poll_internval);
```

Second Activity:

Does the same thing, pulling Xml using another AsyncTask and update UI using onPostExecute.

loop by :

```
Handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, Poll_internval);
```

How should i kill the AsyncTask as it is constantly looping?

Would like to kill it when ending this activity with finish();

Comment: use cancel() method.

Comment: @Md.ShahadatSarker no, it will not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cancel the `AsyncTask`, even with `cancel` method.

You need to implement your logic for canceling the task manually, see this link :

[How to completly kill/remove/delete/stop an AsyncTask in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882543/how-to-completly-kill-remove-delete-stop-an-asynctask-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

```
Asyn mAsyn = new Asyn();
    mAsyn.execute();

    if(mAsyn.isCancelled()){
        mAsyn.cancel(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is provision,
you can remove async task in call back in handler, there is method

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

In Asynctask there is status, you have to develop logic and check status code.

[AsyncTask statuc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html)

In my project, i have same condition and i developed this kind of logic, it work in my code.
please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the androidannotations framework, that has support for running async tasks and also cancelling them. You can checkout the details here:

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads#background]

Basically, all you need to do is annotate the method that needs to run in another thread with

```
@Background(id="cancellable_task")
void someCancellableBackground(String aParam, long anotherParam) {
    [...]
}
```

where "id" is the id of the new thread. Then, to cancel it you just call

```
BackgroundExecutor.cancelAll("id");
```