# Why do I get a source file not found error in the Android class file editor?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application. Are there problems in my code, or is my source file really missing?

[image: source file missing]

Comment: you dont have source code. Jar file contains only class files

Comment: Source code? Do you means there is something that I didn't implemented into my method yet?

Comment: its not a problem. if you wanna see the source code you need download it and attach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to view a file that has been compiled. These files only have the bytecode in them, the language that the device "understands".

Comment: It's not a problem. Which class are you trying to view?

Comment: You could check out Android's open source code: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java
However most chances are that you are asking the wrong question. What are you trying to do and how were you linked to this source?

Comment: AsyncTask class. If it is not a problems, it means that there is something wrong with my code isn't?

Comment: I am learning how to cancel asyncTask while it is progressing. asyncTask is cancelled successfully . But when asyncTask.execute is called again, Source not found is showing as what I mentioned above.

Comment: Well I think you should open a new question asking just that (provided that this doesn't answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821284/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the source code for the android java files you must make sure to download the source via the sdk manager in eclipse.  Then you can attach that source in eclipse so that you will see it instead of what you're seeing now, which is the bytecode.  To attach your source, just click the attach source button and navigate to your sdk folder and there will be a souces folder.  From there you can choose which version sdk to attach.  Good luck!