# Closing application during AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have this application that uses an `AsyncTask` and whenever I decide to close it while it's still running, there's slight lag in the closing. Is there any way to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
private class GetAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Question>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("QA", "Begin GETAPI");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Question> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(urls[0]));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            questions = new ArrayList<>();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        Log.i("QA", "Retrieved question " + i);
                        questions.add(new Question(jo.getString("questionText"), jo.getInt
                                ("magnetid"), "", jo.getInt("personid"), jo.getInt("id")));
                        questions.get(i).setId(jo.getInt("id"));
                    }
                }
            } else
                throw new InputMismatchException("Didn't work");
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return questions;
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Question> strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        Log.i("QA", "End GETAPI");
        QuestionAdapter questionAdapter = new QuestionAdapter(questions);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
        refreshContent(false);
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand why it causes lag on my phone while running the `AsyncTask`and closing this app in the recent applications screen. Is it because I'm not overriding the `onCancel()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) close an AsyncTask using methods provided.  You can tie your cancel calls to the specific lifecycle methods of your Activity.

[How to stop asynctask thread in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821284/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android)