# How to stop asynctask during fragment transactions

Tags: android

I am having issue that if `AsyncTask` is running during fragment transaction then the `fragments` become white(no content is displayed) so is there any way to **stop `AsyncTask` during `fragment` transaction** and resume once transaction is completed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `asyncTask.cancel()` and then your code in `asyncTask.doInBackground()` must test periodically what `isCancelled()` returns,  if true it must return as soon as possible.

Finally when doInBackground returns `asyncTask.onCancelled()` will be called on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep the reference of the `AysncTask` like:

```
MyAysncTask asyncTask = new MyAysncTask();
asyncTask.execute();
```

then in `onPause()`  or before calling `transaction.commit()` call `asyncTask.cancel()`.

Hope it will help!!!

Answer (score 0):

**asyncTask in your activity:**

private YourAsyncTask aTask;

**instanitiate**

```
aTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

**cancel it like this:**

```
aTask.cancel(true);
```

> Original
>   [How to stop asynctask thread in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821284/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android)